# Lightning experience deep link to custom Visualforce tab

Tags: salesforce

Do you know if it is possible to deep link a custom tab on the left hand navigation?

In my web app I allow the user to login through SSO from Salesforce ( so I use salesforce as authentication provider ), than when the user credentials are ensured i redirect the user to the tab using an aspex url like the following:

`https://{domain}/apex/{VisualforceTabsName}?sfdc.tabName={VisualforceTabsRef}`

or a servlet integration link like the following:

`https://na15.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid={lid}&ic=1&linkToken={linkToken}`

I got those links simply right clicking the tabs and copy the link, now this is not going to work on the new ligthening experience where the link is something like the following;

`https://gs0.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#{token}`

Now it seems to me that the token in this case is user specific, so it can't be used as high level reference to the Visualforce tab.

Do you know if there is a way to do the same in the Lightening Experience (Spring 16' release)? Or if there is a different way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning Experience, you can reference custom tabs using the developer name of the tab (note that this is the API name of the tab containing the Visualforce page, not of the page itself). This URL should work:

```
{domain}/lightning/n/{tabName}
```

This assumes that you have already created a tab for your Visualforce page.

Comment: This does not appear to work for the second tier of tabs. I tried variants of /n/{tabName} after the objectID and before and after the view portion of the URL, but nothing seemed to change the selection. is the API name visible from the source of the webpage?

Base: /lightning/r/Account/{ID}/view

Did not work:
/lightning/r/Account/customTab4/{ID}/view
/lightning/r/Account/{ID}/customTab4/view
/lightning/r/Account/{ID}/view/customTab4

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? It sounds like you may be using lightning console, which isn't what the original question was asking about.

Comment: I'm trying to deep link to a [custom] tab on/within an object/detail page. From the other articles I've read my use case is not supported presently.